# Code was fine but not it's throwing error 403 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (Axios YouTube API)

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, axios, youtube-data-api

I was following tutorial: https://blog.bitsrc.io/make-a-simple-react-app-with-using-youtube-api-68fa016e5a03.

I'm a noob so please, if you can help, pretend my name is Layman

I had actually finished, made it beautiful and was adding some additional things (like dislike buttons that dont do anything but look the part)

But now none of it works. I've even reverted my commits really far back to points where I know for show it works but I'm getting the same error. I can only assume its with youtube's api key but I dont know whats wrong. I noticed the issue when i tried to change the maxResults from 5 to 20. It did like that and it hasnt worked since.

I've made a new key, and used a try catch (i think ive done it right) and it still doesnt work

***handle submit in App.jsx***

```
  handleSubmit = async (termFromSearchbar) => {
    // alert(termFromSearchbar);
    try {
      const res = await youtube.get("/search", {
        params: {
          part: "snippet",
          maxResults: 5,
          key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
          q: termFromSearchbar,
        },
      });
      this.setState({
        videos: res.data.items,
        selectedVideo: res.data.items[0],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

***my .env file***
import axios from "axios";

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {
    part: "snippet",
    maxResults: 5,
    key: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that you've exceeded your quota (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

You should verify that first. This document describes how you can do that (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

Comment: I think you're correct - my bumping the search results up must have pushed it over the edge! Thanks